# Função nodejs, funcionamento

Tags: node.js, express.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Ola Mundo');
  });
```

No caso deste código simples só para ilustrar temos uma função em nodejs com 2 parâmetros a requisição e a resposta, eu queria saber se alguém consegue me explicar melhor como isto funciona na integra, afinal o meu conceito de função em outras linguagens e frameworks, quando se tem 2 parâmetros, significa que a função deve receber tais parâmetros.

Como em um caso onde:

```
function area(a, b) {
 c = a.b
 return c
}
```

Ao receber `a` e `b` temos o resultado final retornado `c`, porém no node não é isso que acontece pelo menos a minha perspectiva, o parâmetro REQ de fato é uma requisição do cliente, mas o parâmetro RES normalmente é manipulado dentro da função como um parâmetro de retorno e não de entrada, é como se o requisitante pedisse algo e já desse a resposta, e a gente só trata-se isso e devolve-se o que ele já tem.

Ficou claro a dúvida?
É bom conceitual espero que alguém entenda e consiga me tirar essa dúvida que tá apertando minha mente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começo por dizer que `app.get` é uma função normal que recebe dois parâmetros: Um caminho na forma de `string` e um callback. Logo pode visualizar esta função assim:

```
app.get(caminho, callback);
```

No seu o exemplo o caminho é `'/'` e o callback é `function(req, res){res.send('Ola Mundo');}`.

Após este primeiro ponto, *callbacks* é provavelmente um tópico que irá querer aprofundar, e que será grande parte da confusão. O motivo pelo qual recebe um callback é porque a função é assíncrona e apenas será chamada mais tarde quando um pedido *HTTP* for feito.

Aproveito para fazer um pequeno contra-exemplo da sua função de area com *callbacks*, mas não sem primeiro a corrigir:

```
function area(a, b) {
  let c = a * b;
  return c;
}
```

Esta mesma função poderia ser escrita com um *callback* ainda que não fizesse muito sentido pois não é assíncrona. Mas ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
function area(a, b, callback){
  let c = a * b;
  callback(c);
};

area(10, 5, function(resultado) {
  console.log(resultado);
});
```

Neste exemplo o *callback* é uma função que recebe o resultado e faz qualquer coisa com ele, e faria sentido se fosse assíncrona.

Vamos então modificar este exemplo incluindo um `setTimeout`:

```js
function area(a, b, callback){
  let c = a * b;
  setTimeout(() => callback(c), 2000); //só processa o resultado passado 2 segundos
};

area(10, 5, function(resultado) {
  console.log(resultado);
});

console.log("Calculo leva 2 segundos a ser feito");
```

Repare que em ambos os exemplos não existe `return` pois a função é assíncrona.

Voltando agora ao *Node* e *Express*, o `function(req, res){` é na verdade o *callback*, ou seja a função com o código que você quer que execute quando aquela rota for chamada. Esta pode ser chamada por vários métodos, tais como `get`, `post`, `patch`, `delete`, entre outros e isso é codificado como `string` no primeiro parâmetro. O callback é chamado com dois parâmetros que são objetos e normalmente levam o nome de `req` e `res` respetivamente, embora possam ter qualquer outro nome que queira.

> o parâmetro REQ de fato é uma requisição do cliente

O parâmetro `req` é um objeto com várias das informações do pedido que o cliente fez, tais como:

- `body` - contem pares chave valor do corpo do pedido
- `params` - contem os parâmetros do pedido que são a parte dinâmica do endereço
- `ip` - o endereço ip de onde partiu o pedido

E o `res` é também um objeto que representa a resposta e tem vários métodos para controlar a mesma, tais como:

- `status` - alterar o código http da resposta
- `send` - enviar a resposta com o respetivo corpo
- `redirect` - para redirecionar para outra rota

Aconselho também a dar uma olhada e explorar um pouco a [documentação do Express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) para ficar mais dentro do que representam estes objetos e todas as funcionalidades suportadas

Comment: Muito bom, me passei ali no  a.b, tava digitando sem nem pensar já, Vou dar uma olhada nas documentações e o conceito mais aprofundado de call back.